# How to print rows with pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

```
import pyodbc 
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                      "Server=server_name;"
                      "Database=db_name;"
                      "Trusted_Connection=yes;")


cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Table')

for row in cursor:
    print('row = %r' % (row,))
```

I got output

```
<pyodbc.Cursor object at 0xXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX>
<pyodbc.Cursor object at 0xXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX>
<pyodbc.Cursor object at 0xXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX>
<pyodbc.Cursor object at 0xXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX>
<pyodbc.Cursor object at 0xXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX>
```

Why I can't see the text?

And when I want to print how many rows return with

```
print(len(cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Table')))
```

I got error

```
TypeError: object of type 'pyodbc.Cursor' has no len()
```

1. How can I print rows?
2. How can I print how many rows return?

Comment: You need to fetch the cursor,see fetchone() or fetchall()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rows = cursor.fetchall()

for row in rows:
    print (row)
```

`cursor` is an object which does not behave as a list. So you can't go through as you do with a list.

To make a list from the cursor, use fetchall() method.